# Проблема при запуске кода selenium driver java

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException;

public class sel1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");





    }

}
```

вот что пищет в консоле

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at sel1.main(sel1.java:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Так в стек трейсе ошибки есть ссылка на описание - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Для решения вашей проблемы, попробуйте:

1. Скачать ChromeDriver - https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads и положить куда нибудь на диск(естественно предварительно распаковав). Например создадим папку ChromeDriver на диске С и положим файл туда.
2. Установить property с путем до chromedriver.exe(из шага №1):

   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

Итого ваш код должен быть следующим:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class sel1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо добавил ссылку на драйвер но теперь вылазит новая ошибка в консоле(добавил скрин)

Comment: @div123 попробуйте поиграться с версиями `ChromeDriver`, например скачать v78.

Comment: Поменял версию с 79 на 78 и все заработало спасибо!

Comment: @div123 отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой.Когда обьявляешь драйвер  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() а ниже прописываешь System seproperty то выскакивала точно тоакая же ошибка.Обязательно нужно соблюдать порядок действий. Сначала Setproperty после driver new driver

Comment: Как ваше сообщение отвечает на вопрос ТС? Каких действий и каков их порядок?